# Add HTML input field to Advanced PDF of Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to add a HTML input field to Advanced PDF of Netsuite. We have a requirement from client where we need to add an editable field to the Advanced PDF. If anyone has tried doing this previously please help. I want to add a textarea to the Advanced PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BFO Report Generator documentation has details on how to create PDF form fields.

http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/tags/input.html

http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf (page 57)

The code would look something like

```
<input type="text" name="address" lines="4" scrollable="no" />
```

*However, take note that this functionality is only available in the "Extended Edition" of the Report Generator. I am not sure what version NetSuite licenses.*